# "Keep WiFi on during sleep" on Always not working

Tags: wi-fi, whatsapp-messenger

I have set "Keep WiFi on during sleep" on "always", however it does not seem to work.
The connection keeps established with my router (I can see the wifi icon), however I need to unlock my phone and open WhatsApp before web.whatsapp notices my phone is connected again.
I'm not sure if this is a whatsapp or an android problem, I was hoping someone has the same issue and/or solution.

Comment: Have you tried to disable battery optimization for Whatsapp? What device do you use (manufacturer and model)?

Comment: Hi Robert, I did not had battery optimalization for whatsapp disabled (I didn't even know you could set it on an app-basis). I have disabled it now. I will report back over a week if the issue still presists or not. (ps, I got a samsung s7)

Comment: The changes dont seem to work.